# Email issue when using SMTP PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, smtp-auth

I am working on an email functionality in PHP, SMTP with PHPMailer. In my office we have different servers. Here, it's working fine. But, when I am trying to send mails from outside the office, it doesn't work. I am using SMTP Auth False. I'm providing Hostname and Port number only.

Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not authenticating against the SMTP server probably is because your SMTP works only for your local office network.

For security reasons, your SMTP server may be requesting authentication or just not responding to connections outside your local network.

You need to ask IT guys on your office so they provide you some SMTP credentials to use outside the office.

Comment: Alex is probably right - the SMTP server that you are trying to send through is probably not accessible from the host that you are trying to connect from.  To test if this is the problem, try using telnet to connect to the SMTP server from the host that your PHP is running on, on the port that you are trying to connect to.  Does it connect?

Comment: @Alex, mti2935, thanks for your response. i ll check and update you soon.